# Replace part of a list using 'ReplacePart'

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have two lists, ***List0*** and ***List1*** that have specific structures. I want to replace the second number in each pair of numbers in *List0* with subsequent numbers from a flattened version of ***List1***. This can be achieved easily using **ReplacePart** for a single value from ***List1*** but I haven't succeeded in using subsequent values.

`list0 = {{{12, 34}, {34, 56}}, {{56, 78}, {78, 91}}}; list1 = {{270, 271}, {272, 273}}; list2 = Flatten[list1]; ReplacePart[list0, {_, _, 2} -> list2 ???]`

The final list would take the form:

`{{{12, 270}, {34, 271}}, {{56, 272}, {78, 273}}}`

I suspect that this is quite straightforward but would appreciate an efficient means of accomplishing the task as I have a very great number of these operations to perform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ReplacePart[list0, {_, _, 2} :> Last[list2 = RotateLeft[list2]] ]
```

> ```
> {{{12, 270}, {34, 271}}, {{56, 272}, {78, 273}}}
> ```

Alternatively,

```
k = 1; ReplacePart[list0, {_, _, 2} :> list2[[k++]]]
```

> ```
>  {{{12, 270}, {34, 271}}, {{56, 272}, {78, 273}}}
> ```

Using `Part` assignment:

```
list0 = {{{12, 34}, {34, 56}}, {{56, 78}, {78, 91}}};
list1 = {{270, 271}, {272, 273}};

list0[[All, All, 2]] = list1;
list0
```

> ```
> {{{12, 270}, {34, 271}}, {{56, 272}, {78, 273}}}
> ```

A few additional alternatives:

```
MapAt[Last[list2 = RotateLeft[list2]] &, {All, All, 2}] @ list0

k = 1; MapAt[list2[[k++]] &, {All, All, 2}] @ list0

SubsetMap[list2 &, {All, All, 2}] @ list0
```

Comment: Thank you so much kglr.

Answer (score 5):

**Replace with list1**

If it permitted *not* to Flatten `list1`:

```
ReplacePart[list0, {i_,j_,2} :> list1[[i,j]]]

(* {{{12, 270}, {34, 271}}, {{56, 272}, {78, 273}}} *)
```

**Replace with list2**

If the starting point is a flattened list (`list2`):

```
ReplacePart[list0, {i_,j_,2}:> Partition[list2,2][[i,j]]]

(* {{{12, 270}, {34, 271}}, {{56, 272}, {78, 273}}} *)
```

**Edit**

As pointed out by
[kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr)
in a comment, a better way of replacing with `list2` is the following:

```
ReplacePart[list0, {i_, j_, 2} :> list2[[2 (i - 1) + j]]]

(* {{{12, 270}, {34, 271}}, {{56, 272}, {78, 273}}} *)
```

**Lists**

```
list0
list1
list2

(* {{{12, 34}, {34, 56}}, {{56, 78}, {78, 91}}} *)

(* {{270, 271}, {272, 273}} *)

(* {270, 271, 272, 273} *)
```

Comment: Thank you. It will be interesting to compare the compute speed of these methods. The first by @kglr works perfectly but computation is slow (M1 iMac, 16GB, Mac OS 12.2). I'll run a comparison on the actual data set of 76,800 points.

Comment: That will be interesting. I suspect that kglr's second method will be the fastest by quite a bit, but are you OK with modification in place, or do you require a new list (keeping list0 unmodified)? _Maybe_ something like `list0.{{1,0},{0,0}}+MapThread[List,{ConstantArray[0,Dimensions[#]],#},2]&[list1]`?

Comment: (+1) you can also do `ReplacePart[list0, {i_, j_, 2} :> list2[[2 (i - 1) + j]]]`

Comment: Thank you all. I'll try the options and report back.

Answer (score 4):

**Using `ArrayReduce`:**

```
list0 = {{{12, 34}, {34, 56}}, {{56, 78}, {78, 91}}}; 
list1 = {{270, 
   271}, {272, 273}};

ArrayReduce[Sequence, {First /@ list0, list1}, 1]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{{12, 270}, {34, 271}}, {{56, 272}, {78, 273}}}

Answer (score 3):

```
list0 = {{{12, 34}, {34, 56}}, {{56, 78}, {78, 91}}}; list1 = {{270, 271}, {272, 273}};
```

---

Another way using `Thread`:

```
Map[#[[{1, -1}]] &@*Flatten, Thread /@ Thread[{list0, list1}], {2}]

(*{{{12, 270}, {34, 271}}, {{56, 272}, {78, 273}}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
la = {{{12, 34}, {34, 56}}, {{56, 78}, {78, 91}}};

lb = {{270, 271}, {272, 273}};
```

Define replacement pattern:

```
p = {{{a_, _}, {b_, _}}, {c_, d_}} :> {{a, c}, {b, d}};
```

Using `Replace`

```
Replace[Transpose[{la, lb}], p, {1}]
```

{{{12, 270}, {34, 271}}, {{56, 272}, {78, 273}}}

Using `Cases`

```
Cases[p] @ Transpose[{la, lb}]
```

{{{12, 270}, {34, 271}}, {{56, 272}, {78, 273}}}